# Mount Volume To User's Home Directory In Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to mount a volume to the the user's home directory inside my Docker container.  Inside my `docker-compose.yml` file I have the following Volumes property specified

```
volumes:
  - ./conf:$HOME/conf
```

I would expect this to mount the volume to `/root/conf` but that doesn't appear to happen.  Does Docker/Docker Compose not support environment variable substitution in volume paths?  Is there a way I can mount the volume to the user's home directory without having to know that the home directory is /root inside the container?

Comment: which user - the current user running the docker commands or the user inside the container which is set in the Dockerfile?

Comment: The user inside the container.  My app running inside the container will look for a file in the user's home directory once it is started inside the container.

Comment: I think that is backwards, what I mean is - the app can always look in the same spot, you just mount different things there. The user in the container will always be the same.

Comment: There is no chance that docker someday decides to make the default user something other than root?

Comment: you can control this: USER command in Dockerfile: http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user

Comment: Thanks @Michael that is a good enough solution!

Answer (score 3):

As @Michael mentions in the comments I can use the USER command to ensure that a specific user is used when running the app in the container.  This will allow me to mount the volume to that users home directory and guarantee that the correct files are in place for my app.